# Rotating canvas about axis problems

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graph, html5-canvas

I am using canvas 3d to draw a 3d graph in which i can plot points such as (1,5,4), (-8,6,-2) etc.So i am able to draw in all positive and negative x,y and z axis.I also have rotation effect by using arrow keys.
Instructions for rotation:
The z-axis extends out from the center of the screen.

To rotate about the x-axis, press the up/down arrow keys.
To rotate about the y-axis, press the left/right arrow keys.
To rotate about the z-axis, press the ctrl+left/ctrl+down arrow keys.

I can plot the point by specifying points in the text field i provided.
Now the problem is that for example if i plot(5,5,2) it will plot properly.But if i rotate x axis first and then y axis then point will be plotted properly. The problem comes if i rotate y-axis first and then x-axis.the point will be wrongly plotted.
Easy method to find the problem i encountered:
 This can be easily find out if you go on plotting the same point repeatedly.The point should be plotted above the same point so that only single point is visible.But in my case the same point( for ex(5,5,2) is drawn at different place in canvas while rotating.This problem only comes if i rotate y-axis first and then x-axis or if i rotate z axis first and then y-axis. So what is the mistake i have done in coding.I am new to this canvas 3d and java script.So please help.

```
<html>

 <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>Canvas Surface Rotation</title>

<style>

  body {

    text-align: center;

  }



  canvas {

    border: 1px solid black;

  }

</style>

<script>  

var p1;
var p2;
var p3;
var p4;
var p5;
var p6;
var xangle=0;
var yangle=0;
var zangle=0;
  var constants = {

    canvasWidth: 600, // In pixels.

    canvasHeight: 600, // In pixels.

    leftArrow: 37,

    upArrow: 38,

    rightArrow: 39,

    downArrow: 40,

    xMin: -10, // These four max/min values define a square on the xy-plane that the surface will be plotted over.

    xMax: 10,

    yMin: -10,

    yMax: 10, 

    xDelta: 0.06, // Make smaller for more surface points. 

    yDelta: 0.06, // Make smaller for more surface points. 

    colorMap: ["#000080"], // There are eleven possible "vertical" color values for the surface, based on the last row of http://www.cs.siena.edu/~lederman/truck/AdvanceDesignTrucks/html_color_chart.gif

    pointWidth: 2, // The size of a rendered surface point (i.e., rectangle width and height) in pixels.

    dTheta: 0.05, // The angle delta, in radians, by which to rotate the surface per key press.

    surfaceScale: 24 // An empirically derived constant that makes the surface a good size for the given canvas size.

  };



  // These are constants too but I've removed them from the above constants literal to ease typing and improve clarity.

  var X = 0;

  var Y = 1;

  var Z = 2;



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  



  var controlKeyPressed = false; // Shared between processKeyDown() and processKeyUp().

  var surface = new Surface(); // A set of points (in vector format) representing the surface.



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  function point(x, y, z)

  /*

    Given a (x, y, z) surface point, returns the 3 x 1 vector form of the point.

  */

  {       

    return [x, y, z]; // Return a 3 x 1 vector representing a traditional (x, y, z) surface point. This vector form eases matrix multiplication.

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  function Surface()

  /*

    A surface is a list of (x, y, z) points, in 3 x 1 vector format. This is a constructor function.

  */

  {

    this.points = [];
    // An array of surface points in vector format. That is, each element of this array is a 3 x 1 array, as in [ [x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], [x3, y3, z3], ... ]

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  



  Surface.prototype.equation = function(x, y)

  /*

    Given the point (x, y), returns the associated z-coordinate based on the provided surface equation, of the form z = f(x, y).

  */

  {

    var d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y); // The distance d of the xy-point from the z-axis.



    return 4*(Math.sin(d) / d); // Return the z-coordinate for the point (x, y, z). 

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  



  Surface.prototype.generate = function()

  /*

    Creates a list of (x, y, z) points (in 3 x 1 vector format) representing the surface.

  */

  {

    var i = 0;



    for (var x = constants.xMin; x <= constants.xMax; x += constants.xDelta)

    {

      for (var y = constants.yMin; y <= constants.yMax; y += constants.yDelta)

      {

        this.points[i] = point(x, y, this.equation(x, y)); // Store a surface point (in vector format) into the list of surface points.              

        ++i;

      }

    }

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  Surface.prototype.color = function()

  /*

    The color of a surface point is a function of its z-coordinate height.

  */

  {

    var z; // The z-coordinate for a given surface point (x, y, z).



    this.zMin = this.zMax = this.points[0][Z]; // A starting value. Note that zMin and zMax are custom properties that could possibly be useful if this code is extended later.

    for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++)

    {            

      z = this.points[i][Z];

      if (z < this.zMin) { this.zMin = z; }

      if (z > this.zMax) { this.zMax = z; }

    }   



    var zDelta = Math.abs(this.zMax - this.zMin) / constants.colorMap.length; 



    for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++)

    {

      this.points[i].color = constants.colorMap[ Math.floor( (this.points[i][Z]-this.zMin)/zDelta ) ];

    }



    /* Note that the prior FOR loop is functionally equivalent to the follow (much less elegant) loop:       

    for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++)

    {

      if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#060";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 2*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#090";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 3*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#0C0";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 4*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#0F0";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 5*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#9F0";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 6*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#9C0";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 7*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#990";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 8*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#960";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 9*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#930";}

      else if (this.points[i][Z] <= this.zMin + 10*zDelta) {this.points[i].color = "#900";}          

      else {this.points[i].color = "#C00";}

    }

    */

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function update(){
document.querySelector("#xa").innerHTML = xangle;
document.querySelector("#ya").innerHTML = yangle;
document.querySelector("#za").innerHTML = zangle;
}

  function appendCanvasElement()

  /*

    Creates and then appends the "myCanvas" canvas element to the DOM.

  */

  {

    var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');



    canvasElement.width = constants.canvasWidth;

    canvasElement.height = constants.canvasHeight;

    canvasElement.id = "myCanvas";



    canvasElement.getContext('2d').translate(constants.canvasWidth/2, constants.canvasHeight/2); // Translate the surface's origin to the center of the canvas.



    document.body.appendChild(canvasElement); // Make the canvas element a child of the body element.

  }



  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Surface.prototype.sortByZIndex = function(A, B) 

  {

    return A[Z] - B[Z]; // Determines if point A is behind, in front of, or at the same level as point B (with respect to the z-axis).

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  Surface.prototype.draw = function()

  {

    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // Required for Firefox.

    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var res;
    var xm;


   // this.points = surface.points.sort(surface.sortByZIndex); // Sort the set of points based on relative z-axis position. If the points are visibly small, you can sort of get away with removing this step.


    for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++)

    {

      ctx.fillStyle = this.points[i].color; 

      ctx.fillRect(this.points[i][X] * constants.surfaceScale, this.points[i][Y] * constants.surfaceScale, constants.pointWidth, constants.pointWidth);


    }    

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="12px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillText("X",this.points[p1][X] * constants.surfaceScale, this.points[p1][Y] * constants.surfaceScale);
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx1=c.getContext("2d");
ctx1.font="12px Arial";
ctx1.fillText("Y",this.points[p2][X] * constants.surfaceScale, this.points[p2][Y] * constants.surfaceScale);
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx1=c.getContext("2d");
ctx1.font="12px Arial";
ctx1.fillText("Z",this.points[p3][X] * constants.surfaceScale, this.points[p3][Y] * constants.surfaceScale);

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx1=c.getContext("2d");
ctx1.font="12px Arial";
ctx1.fillText("-Y",this.points[p4][X] * constants.surfaceScale, this.points[p4][Y] * constants.surfaceScale);

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx1=c.getContext("2d");
ctx1.font="12px Arial";
ctx1.fillText("-Z",this.points[p5][X] * constants.surfaceScale, this.points[p5][Y] * constants.surfaceScale);

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx1=c.getContext("2d");
ctx1.font="12px Arial";
ctx1.fillText("-X",this.points[p6][X] * constants.surfaceScale, this.points[p6][Y] * constants.surfaceScale);


  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  Surface.prototype.multi = function(R)

  /*

    Assumes that R is a 3 x 3 matrix and that this.points (i.e., P) is a 3 x n matrix. This method performs P = R * P.

  */

  {

    var Px = 0, Py = 0, Pz = 0; // Variables to hold temporary results.

    var P = this.points; // P is a pointer to the set of surface points (i.e., the set of 3 x 1 vectors).

    var sum; // The sum for each row/column matrix product.



    for (var V = 0; V < P.length; V++) // For all 3 x 1 vectors in the point list.

    {

      Px = P[V][X], Py = P[V][Y], Pz = P[V][Z];

      for (var Rrow = 0; Rrow < 3; Rrow++) // For each row in the R matrix.

      {

        sum = (R[Rrow][X] * Px) + (R[Rrow][Y] * Py) + (R[Rrow][Z] * Pz);

        P[V][Rrow] = sum;

      }

    }     

  }
Surface.prototype.multipt = function(R)

  /*

    Assumes that R is a 3 x 3 matrix and that this.points (i.e., P) is a 3 x n matrix. This method performs P = R * P.

  */

  {

    var Px = 0, Py = 0, Pz = 0; // Variables to hold temporary results.

    var P = this.points; // P is a pointer to the set of surface points (i.e., the set of 3 x 1 vectors).

    var sum; // The sum for each row/column matrix product.



    for (var V = P.length-1; V < P.length; V++) // For all 3 x 1 vectors in the point list.

    {

      Px = P[V][X], Py = P[V][Y], Pz = P[V][Z];

      for (var Rrow = 0; Rrow < 3; Rrow++) // For each row in the R matrix.

      {

        sum = (R[Rrow][X] * Px) + (R[Rrow][Y] * Py) + (R[Rrow][Z] * Pz);

        P[V][Rrow] = sum;

      }

    }     

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  Surface.prototype.erase = function()

  {

    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // Required for Firefox.

    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");



    ctx.clearRect(-constants.canvasWidth/2, -constants.canvasHeight/2, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  Surface.prototype.xRotate = function(sign)

  /*

    Assumes "sign" is either 1 or -1, which is used to rotate the surface "clockwise" or "counterclockwise".

  */

  {

    var Rx = [ [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0] ]; // Create an initialized 3 x 3 rotation matrix.



    Rx[0][0] = 1;

    Rx[0][1] = 0; // Redundant but helps with clarity.

    Rx[0][2] = 0; 

    Rx[1][0] = 0; 

    Rx[1][1] = Math.cos( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Rx[1][2] = -Math.sin( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Rx[2][0] = 0; 

    Rx[2][1] = Math.sin( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Rx[2][2] = Math.cos( sign*constants.dTheta );



    this.multi(Rx); // If P is the set of surface points, then this method performs the matrix multiplcation: Rx * P

    this.erase(); // Note that one could use two canvases to speed things up, which also eliminates the need to erase.

    this.draw();

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  Surface.prototype.yRotate = function(sign)

  /*

    Assumes "sign" is either 1 or -1, which is used to rotate the surface "clockwise" or "counterclockwise".

  */      

  {

    var Ry = [ [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0] ]; // Create an initialized 3 x 3 rotation matrix.



    Ry[0][0] = Math.cos( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Ry[0][1] = 0; // Redundant but helps with clarity.

    Ry[0][2] = Math.sin( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Ry[1][0] = 0; 

    Ry[1][1] = 1;

    Ry[1][2] = 0; 

    Ry[2][0] = -Math.sin( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Ry[2][1] = 0; 

    Ry[2][2] = Math.cos( sign*constants.dTheta );



    this.multi(Ry); // If P is the set of surface points, then this method performs the matrix multiplcation: Rx * P

    this.erase(); // Note that one could use two canvases to speed things up, which also eliminates the need to erase.

    this.draw();

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  Surface.prototype.zRotate = function(sign)

  /*

    Assumes "sign" is either 1 or -1, which is used to rotate the surface "clockwise" or "counterclockwise".

  */      

  {

    var Rz = [ [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0] ]; // Create an initialized 3 x 3 rotation matrix.



    Rz[0][0] = Math.cos( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Rz[0][1] = -Math.sin( sign*constants.dTheta );        

    Rz[0][2] = 0; // Redundant but helps with clarity.

    Rz[1][0] = Math.sin( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Rz[1][1] = Math.cos( sign*constants.dTheta );

    Rz[1][2] = 0;

    Rz[2][0] = 0

    Rz[2][1] = 0;

    Rz[2][2] = 1;



    this.multi(Rz); // If P is the set of surface points, then this method performs the matrix multiplcation: Rx * P

    this.erase(); // Note that one could use two canvases to speed things up, which also eliminates the need to erase.

    this.draw();

  }


Surface.prototype.xRotatept = function()

  {

    var Rx = [ [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0] ]; 



    Rx[0][0] = 1;

    Rx[0][1] = 0; 

    Rx[0][2] = 0; 

    Rx[1][0] = 0; 

    Rx[1][1] = Math.cos(xangle);

    Rx[1][2] = -Math.sin(xangle);

    Rx[2][0] = 0; 

    Rx[2][1] = Math.sin(xangle);

    Rx[2][2] = Math.cos(xangle);


    this.multipt(Rx); 

    this.erase(); 

    this.draw();

  }




  Surface.prototype.yRotatept = function()


  {

    var Ry = [ [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0] ]; 



    Ry[0][0] = Math.cos(yangle);

    Ry[0][1] = 0;

    Ry[0][2] = Math.sin(yangle);

    Ry[1][0] = 0; 

    Ry[1][1] = 1;

    Ry[1][2] = 0; 

    Ry[2][0] = -Math.sin(yangle);

    Ry[2][1] = 0; 

    Ry[2][2] = Math.cos(yangle);



    this.multipt(Ry); 

    this.erase(); 

    this.draw();

  }




  Surface.prototype.zRotatept = function()



  {

    var Rz = [ [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0],

               [0, 0, 0] ];



    Rz[0][0] = Math.cos(zangle);

    Rz[0][1] = -Math.sin(zangle);        

    Rz[0][2] = 0; 

    Rz[1][0] = Math.sin(zangle);

    Rz[1][1] = Math.cos(zangle);

    Rz[1][2] = 0;

    Rz[2][0] = 0

    Rz[2][1] = 0;

    Rz[2][2] = 1;



    this.multipt(Rz); 

    this.erase(); 

    this.draw();

  }




  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  function processKeyDown(evt)

  {                    

    if (evt.ctrlKey)

    {

      switch (evt.keyCode)

      {

        case constants.upArrow: 

          // No operation other than preventing the default behavior of the arrow key.

          evt.preventDefault(); // This prevents the default behavior of the arrow keys, which is to scroll the browser window when scroll bars are present. The user can still scroll the window with the mouse.              

          break;

        case constants.downArrow:

          // No operation other than preventing the default behavior of the arrow key.

          evt.preventDefault();

          break;

        case constants.leftArrow:

          // console.log("ctrl+leftArrow");
                zangle=zangle-0.05;
                update();
        if(zangle<=-2*Math.PI)
        {
            zangle=0;

        }
          surface.zRotate(-1); // The sign determines if the surface rotates "clockwise" or "counterclockwise". 

          evt.preventDefault(); 

          break;

        case constants.rightArrow:

          // console.log("ctrl+rightArrow");
            zangle=zangle+0.05;
            update();
        if(zangle>=2*Math.PI)
        {
            zangle=0;

        }
          surface.zRotate(1);

          evt.preventDefault(); 

          break;

      }

      return; // When the control key is pressed, only the left and right arrows have meaning, no need to process any other key strokes (i.e., bail now).

    }



    // Assert: The control key is not pressed.



    switch (evt.keyCode)

    {

      case constants.upArrow:

        // console.log("upArrow");

        xangle=xangle+0.05;
        update();
        if(xangle>=2*Math.PI)
        {
            xangle=0;

        }

        surface.xRotate(1);

        evt.preventDefault(); 

        break;

      case constants.downArrow:

        // console.log("downArrow");
        xangle=xangle-0.05;
        update();
        if(xangle<=-2*Math.PI)
        {

            xangle=0;
        }

        surface.xRotate(-1); 

        evt.preventDefault(); 

        break;

      case constants.leftArrow:

        // console.log("leftArrow");
        yangle=yangle-0.05;
        update();
        if(yangle<=-2*Math.PI)
        {
            yangle=0;

        }
        surface.yRotate(-1);  

        evt.preventDefault(); 

        break;

      case constants.rightArrow:

        // console.log("rightArrow");
        yangle=yangle+0.05;
        update();
        if(yangle>=2*Math.PI)
        {
            yangle=0;

        }
        surface.yRotate(1);   

        evt.preventDefault(); 

        break;

    }

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Surface.prototype.plot = function(x, y, z)
  /*
    add the point (x, y, z)  (in 3 x 1 vector format) to the surface.
  */
  {

        this.points.push(point(x, y, z)); // Store a surface point
        var x=0;
        for (var x = constants.xMin; x <= constants.xMax; x += constants.xDelta)
        {
        this.points.push(point(x, 0, 0));
        }
        p6=1;
        p1=this.points.length-1;
        p4=this.points.length;
        /*var y=-0.2
        for (var x = constants.xMax+1; x <= constants.xMax+2; x += constants.xDelta)
        {
        this.points.push(point(x, y, 0));
        y=y+0.002
        }*/

        /*for (var x = constants.xMax+1; x <= constants.xMax+2; x += constants.xDelta)
        {
        this.points.push(point(11, 0, 0))
        }*/
        for (var x = constants.xMin; x <= constants.xMax; x += constants.yDelta)
        {
        this.points.push(point(0, x, 0));   
        }
        p2=this.points.length-1;
        p5=this.points.length;
        for (var x = constants.xMin; x <= constants.xMax; x += constants.yDelta)
        {
        this.points.push(point(0,0,x)); 
        }
        p3=this.points.length-1;

  }
  Surface.prototype.plot1 = function(x, y, z)
  /*
    add the point (x, y, z)  (in 3 x 1 vector format) to the surface.
  */
  {      


        this.points.push(point(x, y, z)); // Store a surface point
    surface.xRotatept();
    surface.yRotatept();

    surface.zRotatept();
        this.draw();

  }


  function onloadInit()

  {

    appendCanvasElement(); // Create and append the canvas element to the DOM.

    surface.draw(); // Draw the surface on the canvas.

    document.addEventListener('keydown', processKeyDown, false); // Used to detect if the control key has been pressed.

  }



  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




  //surface.generate(); // Creates the set of points reprsenting the surface. Must be called before color().
surface.plot(0,0,0);
  surface.color(); // Based on the min and max z-coordinate values, chooses colors for each point based on the point's z-ccordinate value (i.e., height).

  window.addEventListener('load', onloadInit, false); // Perform processing that must occur after the page has fully loaded.

    </script>

 </head>

  <body>
<table align="center">
<tr><td>
<h5 style="color:#606">Enter the value of (X,Y,Z)</h5>
            <input type="text" value="5" class="num-input" width="50" size="2" id="x-input">
            <input type="text" value="5" class="num-input" width="50" size="2" id="y-input">
            <input type="text" value="2" class="num-input" width="50" size="2" id="z-input">
            <input type="button" value="Plot Point" onClick="surface.plot1(document.getElementById('x-input').value,document.getElementById('y-input').value,document.getElementById('z-input').value); ">

            </td></tr></table>
<table align="center"> <tr><td>
<span id="xa">0</span>deg<br>
<span id="ya">0</span>deg<br>
 <span id="za">0</span>deg</td></tr></table>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, bwroga I correct.  You need to accumulate all your rotations into one final transform matrix. Here is a really great tutorial on 3d rotation and their transform matrices -- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_orthographic_3d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final output of rotations along multiple axis can vary depending on the order that you rotate the axis'. What you need to do is keep track of the total rotation along each axis (as three numbers, not using matrices). And each time you update a rotation value, apply all three total rotations to an identity matrix in the correct order (try x,y,z). Always use the same order. Then use this to transform your coordinates.

Comment: Now i am storing the angle of rotation along each x,y and z axis in separate variable and then i am applying the rotation matrix along x and then y and then z.Is this correct what i am doing?

Comment: @Navaneet That should be correct. Just don't forget to reset the rotation matrix to an identity matrix each time before applying the rotations.

Comment: what i did is plotting a point in xyz plane or graph and then rotating as i want.During rotation i keep track of angle rotated for x,y,z axis. Then if plot a new point then i don't reset the x,y and z axis instead i plot the point in the same plane which was in some rotated mode. What ever may be order of rotation i did i apply rotation matrix for that point about x axis first and then y and finally z. but still i am getting error. Also during rotating about a axis i am tracking angle rotation for that axis only.Is that ok?

Comment: @Navaneet You should always plot your points as if there was no rotation, then when you are ready to draw, create a new array of points with the rotation applied. Whenever you update the rotation, remultiply the un-transformed points with the rotation matrix to get your rotated points. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes. i am applying rotation matrix to only new points to be plotted. But my doubt is there any order to apply the rotation matrix according to rotation applied along axis.Also please look at code i provided above.

Comment: @Navaneet I looked at your code and tested it in the browser. You always need to keep track of the unrotated positions of the points. And whenever you update the rotation of the canvas, or add a new point, re-rotate all the points using your rotation matrix. Never change the actual point rotations. Always change a copy of them that you make fresh each time you need to update. And use the copy to draw the rotated points.

Comment: Can u please tell me how can i set a particular color for every axis?I want different colors for every axis.

Comment: You create your three axes in the plot() function, so each time you create an axis, assign every point in that axes the color you want. The problem is, that in your surface.prototype.color() function you rewrite all the colors. So you will have to rethink how you do this. It might be good to store the axes points separately from the other points.

Comment: Yes. i did it by storing the axis x, y and z axis points separately and gave diff color for each axis. Also i have done all changes you have mentioned before.Now the i hav a 3d graph with plot points and also plotting equations etc. thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

here is my opinion:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle='#333';

ctx2.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


ctx.fillStyle='red';

var deg = Math.PI/180;

ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(100, 100);
    ctx.rotate(45 * deg);
    ctx.fillRect(-50,-50,100,100);
ctx.restore();
```

ctx2 is the old position and ctx is the new position of the shape. You have to translate the shape with the same x,y coordinates according to where you want position your shape. Then you have to enter values to `ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);`keep x and y as the -ve values (half of height and width to keep it on the diagonal to the canvas otherwise change to manipulate it). and h, w as your desired values.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anshalexander/HTxGb/55/)**